# Unknown column '...' in 'where clause PHP/MySQL issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with this program I am testing on my localhost server. Every time I enter values into the form and select a course from the drop down menu I am getting the error message (where "...." is the course name I have selected):

```
Unknown column '.....' in 'where clause'
```

EDIT2 This is the code I have used to create the tables with full index:

```
include 'login.php';
$link = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS) or die (mysql_connect_error());
mysql_select_db('graham', $link);

$query1 = "CREATE TABLE course (name VARCHAR(50), code VARCHAR(10), max INT(2))";
$query2 = "CREATE TABLE students (name VARCHAR(50), studentnum VARCHAR(50), FULLTEXT (name,studentnum))ENGINE=MyISAM";
$query3 = "CREATE TABLE enrolled (student VARCHAR(50), studentnum VARCHAR(50), course VARCHAR(50), FULLTEXT (student,studentnum,course))ENGINE=MyISAM";

$result1 = mysql_query ($query1, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query ($query2, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result3 = mysql_query ($query3, $link) or die(mysql_error());

$querya = "ALTER TABLE students ADD FULLTEXT(name)";
$queryb = "ALTER TABLE students ADD FULLTEXT(studentnum)";
$queryc = "ALTER TABLE enrolled ADD FULLTEXT(student)";
$queryd = "ALTER TABLE enrolled ADD FULLTEXT(studentnum)";
$querye = "ALTER TABLE enrolled ADD FULLTEXT(course)";

$result4 = mysql_query ($querya, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result5 = mysql_query ($queryb, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result6 = mysql_query ($queryc, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result7 = mysql_query ($queryd, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result8 = mysql_query ($querye, $link) or die(mysql_error());




$query4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO course (name, code, max) 
VALUES
('HTML', 'PROG-1288', 4),
('Javascript', 'PROG-2283', 3),
('Dreamweaver','MEDA-1380', 4),
('Photoshop','PHOT-1382', 3)") or die (mysql_error());

$query5 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO students (name, studentnum) 
VALUES
('GerrardLooper', 987654),
('BruceLee', 123456),
('JoeSchmoe', 236728),
('JaneDoe', 111222),
('JoeSchmoe', 128790)") or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT name FROM course";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'><pre>";
echo "Please select a course: ";
echo "<select name='coursename'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "\nStudent Name <input type='text' name='studentname' />";
echo "\nStudent Number <input type='text' name='studentnum' />\n";
echo "<input type='submit' name='addrecord' value='ADD RECORD' />";
echo "</pre></form>";

mysql_close($link);
```

And here is the code I am using when trying to match what the user has selected against the data in the tables:

```
//check if name and student number match the records in the database
$name1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentname']);
$num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentnum']);
$qw = "SELECT name FROM students WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('".$name1."')";
$qw1 = "SELECT studentnum FROM students WHERE MATCH (studentnum) AGAINST ('".$num."')";
$namematch = mysql_query($qw) or die(mysql_error());
$nummatch = mysql_query($qw1) or die(mysql_error());

if (($namematch || $nummatch) == FALSE) {
    die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
}
```

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question @cornelb

Comment: you don't seem to have FULLTEXT index in your columns but you are trying to use MATCH .. AGAINST

Comment: if you have FULLTEXT then you are not showing us the real code. since this works without any problems: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/838e39/1
try echoing the error producing query so we can see what you **actually** are sending to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

MATCH(...) AGAINST syntax can only be used with FULLTEXT index. try adding FULLTEXT index to your relevant columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD FULLTEXT(name);
ALTER TABLE students ADD FULLTEXT(studentnum);
```

working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42cf9/1)